# Why do many commercial aircraft have a red circle on the wing?

Tags: wing

Many commercial aircraft operated by japanese airlines like JAL and ANA have a red circle on the wing. Look:
[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Japan-Airlines--/Boeing-777-346-ER/186707/&sid=642aaf8510690405db58594bfcd8d0c1)

And on this ANA plane, also:
[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/All-Nippon-Airways/Boeing-777-381-ER/1505780/L/&sid=5599cde0f980e11a2ee88871be9ef9fa)

Why do they have that red circle there?

Comment: This is a genuine question and does not deserve all the downvotes. (Although it's an easy/naive one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be the Japanese sun symbol which also appears on that nation's flag. You can also see that symbol on the tail of that JAL 777 on top.

Same as the Japanese Flag:
[image]

Comment: A [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+air+force&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBmtr-m7HLAhUJ8CYKHTG0DdkQ_AUIBygB&biw=1117&bih=1078) for "Japanese air force" will show that red circle somewhere on every aircraft pictured.

Answer (score -1):

May be another example:

Emirates airline:

[image]

and the flag of the United Arab Emirates:

[image]